# Filter Solr Documents before sending it to the user

Tags: solr

I want to perform a comparison based on one field in a Solr document before it is sent to the Writer or to the user. I want to have the final result object, probably `SolrDocumentList`, so that I can loop through all the `SolrDocument` objects and perform a field to field comparison. For instance, if my search returns 10 documents and 5 documents have myfield="myValue", my final list should contain 6 documents with only one document having myfield="myValue", the other 4 documents should be discarded, regardless of what the other fields' contents are.

Is there any plugin for this?

If not, where should I place my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Result Grouping / Field Collapsing. Try some thing like this: &q=solr+memory&group=true&group.field=manu_exact&group.main=true

More documenation here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing